# What's the overhead associated with the `#[transactional]` macro?

Tags: pallet, storage, runtime, weight

Substrate has a macro, [`#[transactional]`](https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/attr.transactional.html), to ensure that any modifications to storage are not persisted in case of an error during execution.

I imagine there's some sort of caching done before committing any changes to the underlying database, and I was curious to know what kind of overhead was associated with annotating a function as `#[transactional]`.

Maybe as a simple metric, if we consider two functions - one tagged with transactional and another not, how many more times could we execute the non-transactional function vs. the transactional function in the same amount of time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Benchmark results for the `#[transactional]` overhead can be found here:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/10809

The key takeaways:

- Spawning a transactional layer is quite cheap; just 50 nanoseconds per layer.
- Writing 1,000 storage item between one layer is 146,163 nanoseconds, so ~146 nanoseconds per storage item.

  - When compared to the weight of a write in RocksDB (100,000 nanoseconds), the overhead is only .15%, which is extremely nominal.

This is why we are interested to make `#[tranasctional]` the default behavior across all Substrate extrinsics.

A specification can be found here:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/10806

The main concern to have with using `#[transactional]` today is to ensure you prevent a potential stack overflow by a malicious user spawning too many of them in a transaction.

This is why in my proposal, I set an upper limit to the number of layers that can be spawned, and return an error when trying to spawn more layers.

Additionally, we will make spawning a new layer an explicit action, so that most users will not run into this limit when writing code.

Comment: Is each 'layer' a nested declaration of `#[transactional]`? 
How could a malicious user spawn too many layers?

Comment: Yes. You can imagine making an extrinsic transactional that can dispatch another extrinsic. For example, `batch_all` is transactional. Without any blockers, you could do `batch_all(batch_all(batch_all(...` which would nest a bunch of layers. We actually wrote code in the pallet to explicitly prevent this right now.

Answer (score 4):

One thing to keep in mind is that the the size of the storage items do not matter for the overhead. They are kept as `Vec` in the overlay and are moved around without copying.

You pay `O(#dirty_keys)` on each commit or discard. Most notably the read and write performance for keys are unaffected by the current layering depth. More information can be found in the original PR:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/6269